# Can I do a 125A subpanel feeder with slightly-larger-than-#3 wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

How they are all connected:

[image]

With all the details and data given below. So Can I do a 125A subpanel feeder with slightly-larger-than-#3 wire?

This is detail directly related to the post.

[image]

Question. When the 30mm^2 wire reaches 90C degrees (the red and black wire going to the aluminum terminals after main breaker in main panel). What is the temperature that can reach the terminal of the breaker? Do you think the temperature can lower to 75C at terminal or since it is cooper with maximum conduction, then temperature at terminal is also 90C? (btw the smaller wires going to the Lugs is the Siemens Whole House First Surge SPD 140,000A. I have to put this here to both protect the main panel and subpanel without increasing length).

To visualize it all. The following are complete pictures of subpanel and main panel (see related post about 6 circuits inside Raceway and possible deratement [Is this 6 circuits inside a Raceway that calls for 50% deratement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156429/is-this-6-circuits-inside-a-raceway-that-calls-for-50-deratement))
Also this thread was started by Harper who happened to directly influence me to put the subpanel first by convincing me the autotransformer can power the Siemens 2-pole GFCI breakers and I can't put them in generic brand plug in panel (thanks to him and Ed Beal who taught me and gave me guts to put the lugs on the terminal after main breaker in main panel to connect to the subpanel (with all GFCI breakers inside the subpanel)). Without them I couldn't have done it.

[image]

[image]

jtl also Samzun (account maximum questions reached & disallowed to ask questions in electronics stack exchange and here)

update yesterday:

I found out something unfortunate. My townhouse main panel to the service entrance outside (we are 5 townhouse in compound) is about 30 meters away and it uses only 38mm^2 (between AWG 1 and 2) with 150A service entrance main breaker connected to my house 125A main panel main breaker. For 150A. It requires AWG 1/0 wire.

[image]

[image]

The above was file photo where I was plotting ground voltage gradient in case I'd put GEC (Ground Electrode Conductor) but difficult because have to demolish the parking (it is not possible to replace the 38mm^2 wire too because it zigzaged many unknown angles and neighbors don't want the parking demolished).

So the 150A breaker will never trip because the 30 meter wire used is only 38mm^2 (AWG 1 is 42.4mm^2 for comparison). Therefore I can't use 1/0 between my subpanel and main panel inside the house because the 30 meter 38mm^2 would burn first before my planned 1/0 in subpanel, isn't it?  Now if I use 38mm^2 in subpanel to main panel which at 75C is 120A. Would the 125A main breaker in house trip before my subpanel 38mm^2 wire burns or would the wire burn and the 125A main breaker tripping at same time? When a wire is listed for 120A at 75C. Does it mean at exactly 120A, the insulation would suddenly catch fire? I need to understand exactly this process so can decide whether to retain the 30mm^2 or upgrade to 38mm^2. It's no longer an option for me to upgrade to 1/0 because of the 30 meter 38mm^2 between my house main panel and the compound service entrance breakers, isn't it?

Here is my subpanel wires to the subpanel lugs (the big red and black at middle):

[image]

On right of it 3 inches away is the main panel (with 125A main breaker where the feeder wires are directly tapped off in the breaker terminal 1.5 inches away). The feeder wires are only 1 meter. Besides asking if 30mm^2 (between AWG 2 and 3) is sufficient. I want to know what is the biggest wire (1/0?) that you can still bend into the lugs inside the subpanel. Since it's just 1 meter wire, no problem replacing it with the biggest allowable. Note the hole to the subpanel has been grinded smooth so it won't cut the wires. No conduit is used because I couldn't find an exact 3" conduit so I inserted the load wires into black mica tube. Note the load wires coming into the subpanel were taken from the main panel load. So imagine the main panel has only half of the load and half of the breakers were just turned off.

Detail: The conduit length between main panel and subpanel is exactly 1 meter and connected directly to each other through hole at the sides of the panels. Initially my subpanel has a 100A main breaker (but it was defective and can't exchange it anymore). So I chose 30mm^2 to match the 100A with 125A main breaker in main panel. My mistake was not matching the wire to the 125A. So now the subpanel is Lugs only with maximum rating of 125A. So I both have subpanel and main panel that is 125A. Since 1 meter is just short. I want to change the feeder wire. Should I need 1, or 1/0 or even 2/0? Can I use 75C?

Original by Harper:

I want to run a 125A feeder to a subpanel.  This is actually main feed, tapped directly below (after) my main breaker which is 125A. I don't want to use another breaker in the main panel.

I already have, on-hand, copper 30mm2 THHN wire, which is halfway between #3 and #2 in size.   Is there any way I can use this wire for that purpose?  My line of thinking is

- I get an 83% uprate because it's feeder off the main service breaker.
- And since I am over 100A, I don't need to stick to the [60C](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156077/60c-or-75c-wiring-for-60c-75c-breaker-output-heatsink) column.  I am willing to spend the money on 90C terminations if that will help. Changing lugs at both ends is possible.
- Also this wire being bigger than #3, does that buy me anything?  Can I calculate off actual wire size rather than AWG?

Phillipines but following NEC. [Asking for another asker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/155791/does-the-subpanel-feeder-need-to-match-the-main-breaker-size).

Comment: What size is the main breaker where you are tapping in? I understand you want a 125a sub but if not using a breaker tapping after your existing main the wire ampacity would need to be at least that size. Over 100 amps you can use the 75 degree table, to use 90 deg colum you would need to lug prior the sub and then upsize for a short distance to the main in the sub unless you can find a 90 degree breaker per NEC 215.2 see exhibit 215.1.

Comment: The 83% is only good for the main service panel but I will need to find the code reference., no it is for service and feeders 310.15.b.7.  But I have not used it that way in the past because it states service conductors supplying the entire load associated with an individual dwelling. So the wording is questionable to me, don't think they would allow it in Oregon.

Comment: This is a very good question, especially since the NEC ampacity tables don't address metric wire sizes.

Comment: Also, is this in conduit *on* a wall, or conduit or cable embedded *in* an insulating wall?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don,t know as I'm asking to advance [another question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156115/can-i-do-a-125a-subpanel-feeder-with-slightly-larger-than-3-wire).

Comment: @Harper -- will ask there

Comment: I added this detail to the post above: "Detail: The conduit length between main panel and subpanel is exactly 1 meter and connected directly to each other through hole at the sides of the panels. Initially my subpanel has a 100A main breaker. So I chose 30mm^2 to match the 100A with 125A main breaker in main panel. My mistake was not matching the wire to the 125A. So now the subpanel is Lugs only with maximum rating of 125A. So I both have subpanel and main panel that is 125A. Since 1 meter is just short. I want to change the feeder wire. Should I need 1, or 1/0 or even 2/0? Can I use 75C? "

Comment: Btw.. to add more details. The 100A main breaker in subpanel got defective. And I couldn't replace it anymore since it has to be handed to physical address in US. Well. I'll replace the 30mm^2 with either 38mm^2 or 50mm^2. 1 meter is just cheap. Would 38mm^2 or 50mm^2 suffice? I want the 125A main breaker in main panel to trip before the wire burns. This is the brand and spec of all my wires.. https://phelpsdodge.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/COPPER-BUILDING-WIRE-TYPE-THHNTHWN-21.pdf

Comment: I'm reading a lot about this because it would be my last electrical detail I need to handle. What is the technical reasoning for " 83% uprate because it's feeder off the main service breaker". I know 83% means even if your main breaker in main panel is 125A. You can use 125A x 0.83 = 103.75A wire. But I need technical explanations why it is so more than blindly following codes that may just be copied. Does it simply mean family dwelling never use the full 125A? Or they have over 25% safety margin in the computations. How do they actually compute for ampere, wire size and temperature?

Comment: I for one am reluctant to state NFPA's rationale for a particular rule.  Knowing NFPA, there are multiple reasons such as A B C D and when E interacts with F.  The problem is everytime I say "the reason is A", someone clever goes "A doesn't apply to me, therefore, the rule doesn't apply to me" and then they get nailed by B.  The Philippine authority may copy things (they could do worse than copy NEC) but NFPA does nothing without good reason.  I have never found a rule that proved to be stupid.

Comment: Anyway, the way the facts are lining up, it appears 30mm2 will suffice.  I'm hoping someone will write an answer.

Comment: I think the rational of the 83% in the subpanel feeder wire is that since it's connected directly to the main breaker of the main panel. Then it means the main breaker at main panel is splitting the current between the subpanel and its own branches. So the logic is, how can the entire 125A current goes to the subpanel when it has its own branches? The owner should have increased the main panel to 200A if there is more load. But there is actually no additional load. It's shared half half, the reason being half of  the original main panel bus bar is bent and not shiny and I want extra subpanel.

Comment: Is replacing the 30mm2 wire an option, given the short length of the run and that you'll need to undo and redo this anyway in order to fit the conduit nipple between the panels?

Comment: Yes. I want to replace it so no hidden overload issues in future and burning wires. So with 125A main breaker in main panel and 125A subpanel lugs. The table for AWG 1 at 75C is 130A, can I use 75C & AWG 1? AWG 1 is equal to 42.4mm^2. Here we only have 38mm^2 then jump to 50mm^2. Your AWG 1/0 is 53.47mm^2. So it's like I need to put AWG 1/0 since there is nothing between 38mm^2 and 50mm^2.But the question is, can you bend AWG 1/0 with bare hands or need special tool And can it be 90 degree angle from the conduit nipple to the lugs or soft bend? Is AWG 1/0 more fragile and can't be bend twice?

Comment: To add to the comment above. The loads in the subpanel are three electric bath heater with 33A each.So just the heaters can reach 100A if used simultaneously. The subpanel is also connected to two fridges, water pump, washing machine, all room outlets. It is connected to all the power in the house except the lights and air conditioners. Der4 I decided to use 1/0 or 50mm^2.But in my subpanel.Can you bend it with such small spacing?So hope one can finally give Answer how to bend a 1/0 wire inside the subpanel It's just one meter only and not 20 meters so not upgrading the wire is not good idea.

Comment: What do you mean by 50% derate? You mean you can just use 45C wire instead of 90C? Any reference I can read more? Also I need to know something. All my breakers in main panel is 30A. Some has load of only a few ampere like 2A or 5A at most. Can I join two circuits together in one subpanel breaker but also using the same 30A? Thanks so much Harper. The splice will be done at main panel side. Imagine 2 circuits being joined with a an extra wire using the red wire nut to join 3 pcs of AWG 10 together. The wire nut works I have tried it. Just want to know about any problem of joining circuits.

Comment: But notice in the picture it's open space. Is it not raceway is strictly when they are inside a closed tube that is longer and hence can prevent conduction of temperature away from inside the tube?  Also there is nothing wrong with joining two circuits in two 30A breakers into one 30A breaker as long as the breaker amperage is the same, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, well if the wall in the left of the main panel pic is the same as the right hand wall in the subpanel pic,disregard my comments about 50% derate. When you finally do enclose that in a conduit, gutter or raceway, the raceway will be less than 24" (600mm) and so, the derate does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I am able to put together on the applicability of 30mm wire as subpanel feeder hot off a main breaker.

First, the allowable ampacity of the wire.   Let's look at table 310.15b16, with an added column for mm2.

```
  Gauge      mm2    At 60C   At 75C   At 90C
 3 AWG       26.7      85      100      115
             30.0       ?       ?        ?
 2 AWG       33.6      95      115      130
             38.0       *       *        * 
 1 AWG       42.4     110      130      145
```

Assuming values are linear/proportional, and they are linear enough in such a small zone, the ? numbers  are 90, 107, and 122, respectively.

### The 125A-breakered interpanel feeder

Because we are over 100A, we are not constrained by rule that requires us to use the 60C column for feeder.  We can use the 75C or even possibly 90C column if the terminations and wire are rated for it. THHN is.

Now, because this is a feeder taken straight off the main breaker, we get a derate (uprate, really) of 83% (NEC 310.15b7)The planned service is 125A.  83% of that is 
104.

104 is less than 107.  **30mm2 wire is adequate for this feeder.**

### The 150A-breakered service conductors

What about the outside feeder, breakered at 150A?  Looking again at our modified 310.16 table, you see where the area of 38mm2 wire is dead-nuts halfway between #2 and #1.  So, looking at the * numbers, we interpolate exactly halfway between.  Giving 102.5, 122.5 and 137.5 respectively.

Assuming we are stuck in the 75C column, we use 122.5.  Being a service supply, we "derate" (uprate) 122.5 by 83% giving 147.6 amps.

147.6 amps is less than 150.  But: 147.6 amp breakers are not readily available, so we are allowed to round up to the nearest available size.  That being 150A.

**The 38mm service supply is appropriately breakered** by NEC standards.

### Other questions

You are *always* allowed to use larger wire than required. If Code requires #3 and you have a perfect-length scrap of #00 lying around, go for it.

The 150A breaker *should* rarely trip because the very next stop downline is a 125A breaker.   This is not reliable; coordination of breakers is a black art.  However, if the 38mm service wires themselves developed a short, the breaker would come into play.

---

Comment: Thanks I just saw this message, missed it earlier today. I just found out my 100A subpanel Siemens main breaker is not entirely defective. If after turning it on, I pushed it a bit (hear the click in this new video https://youtu.be/tCqGNRzIMO0), it will remain on. Assuming I can use the 100A breaker in subpanel. So it can trip at 100A and not 125A. This is better protection isn't it?  because now I have almost 4 main breakers in series to the service entrance.

Comment: @Jtl as I just showed, your wire is just the right size to be legal at the larger size.  But the extra breaker can't hurt.

Comment: What if i migrated all the main panel loads into the subpanel? Im computing my exact loads including two critical bath heaters. If they are ballpark and can fit into the subpanel load capacity. Does your derating analysis still appy? Or with all loads in subpanel. Must I now require full 125A feeder between subpanel and main panel?

Comment: If you migrated all the main loads to the subpanel, then it would be the only panel and the 83% friendly derate *up to it* would definitely apply.

Comment: The logic or philosophy of derate is because residential wont use full load like 125A but what if your house has visitors and you use the full load of 125A then the derate of 104A and wire made for 104A can become overload, right?

Comment: After reading about the rule in NEC 310.15b7 for hours & researching deeper and especially taking your context and Answer into account. I learnt the 83% is for both feeder and conductor for the same overcurrent (or breakers). So if the computed load and overcurrent breaker is 150A. Then the wiring should be 124.5A (or let's say 38mm^2 at 122.5A can be used). So it should be 38mm^2 only for service/feeder. Therefore the 125A breaker is wrongly put. It should be 150A breaker only and 38mm^2 all throughout. Why did you accept the 125A from the 150A as valid when 125A should not be allowed?

Comment: @Jtl because if safety requires a 150A breaker, a 125A breaker does no harm.

Comment: Ok got it. I'll order a 125A Schneider din rail MCB then  https://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product/A9N18363/c120n---circuit-breaker---2p---125a---c-curve and use 38mm^2 wire to the Siemens panel. This way at least there is 125A allowance. I think this main breaker will be perfect, I'm assuming the 150A outside has rusty inside that i'm afraid when turned off, it can't be turned on anymore because of rusty spring too.. lol

Comment: please see https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157182/how-to-put-din-rail-breakers-enclosure-over-old-plug-in-panel-case for major changes after I realized a major mistake by old contractor.