# Arc flash thin sheet to cover panel cabinet & fixing the wires

Tags: electrical

This is the panel cover.

[image]

back side of the cover

[image]

Background. You need EGC (Equipment Ground Conductor) in metal chassis of anything in the house. But in poor country Philippines where 100% of homes don't have any EGC. The main panel chassis is not protected. I can protect the fridge, washing machine etc. metal chassis by putting them under GFCI breaker control (in fact I did). But how about the panel chassis. I've been wondering this for months. Someone even suggested I put a 30ma RCD before the panel. But if it trips, the entire house power goes down.

Therefore one of my solution is to treat the entire panel metal chassis as live. Meaning it shouldn't be touched without first turning off the power in a lone 2nd disconnect on right of it. Putting the huge cover can defeat the purpose. More if a gutter (large junction box) would be flushed to it as someone suggested. It would increase the surface area in case of ground fault.

What do you think of this logic? Therefore something light (preferably that can't conduct) can be put to cover inside wooden cabinet or even a child bathtub to cover the entire inside panel. Then smoke detector could be put inside. This would be safer than electrified panel chassis can easily electrocute anyone touching it. Isn't it? In a main panel without EGC, need to improvise.

In the following original panel. I wanted to join circuits in 3 breakers into one subpanel breaker. 2 breakers into 1, etc.

[image]

The one labeled in blue are 3 breakers that I joined into one breaker in the subpanel (the loadings of the 3 are less than 15A). I first used wire nut (3-wire) to tie two breakers with extra wire to another wire nut to join the 3rd breaker into the subpanel. In the green labels, I tried to join 2 circuits/breakers into one breaker. The one in yellow is one circuit/breaker only and adding butt splice to make longer wire into the subpanel breaker. 1 and 2 is the bath heater wires directly to the subpanel. 
Here is the result:

[image]

The above is just a start. It would get messier. I planned to migrate the rest of the circuits/breakers into the subpanel for total whole house GFCI breaker protection.

If I join the wires in the gutter (large junction box below the panel) suggested by Harper. Should I continue to use wire nuts to join 3 circuits/breakers into one breaker (the breaker ampere is the same 30A for all so no problem about overloading any wires).

Or another alternative. I could just cover the wooden cabinet with insulation/thin metal to make the entire cabinet the metal cover? So I'm looking for a thin sheet of material insulator that is fireproof and arc flash proof that you can put over wood (or cover the wood with), any idea what that would be?

Comment: That is a fairly vague question. The answer might vary depending on the size of the area to be covered, the expected temperatures and how how "fireproof" does it need to be - e.g., 15 minutes, 1 hour, 4 hours? Even the type of wood may affect it. Permanent installation or temporary (e.g., for covering something while welding nearby)?

Comment: It will cover the inside of the wooden cabinet at center here to protect from any arc flash from the panel https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156429/is-this-6-circuits-inside-a-raceway-that-calls-for-50-deratement  It's just theoretical explorations of possibility and for knowledge as other options are still being contemplated.

Comment: Then the question is whether it needs to be an *insulator*. The simplest/cheapest/easiest "fireproof & arc flash proof" in general would be sheet metal - similar to the stuff used for the breaker panel enclosures. But that is not an *insulator*.

Comment: Yes, thin GI metal sheet is my first option.. but I was wondering if there are others that is an insulator that can compete with it, maybe some kind of fiberglass sheet?

Comment: My first thought was "asbestos" - insulates, protects from fire, etc. but there is a little problem of lung cancer... I have no idea how fiberglass would do for this (though it is safer than asbestos!)

Answer (score 3):

> **I'm looking for a thin sheet of material insulator that is fireproof and arc flash proof that you can put over wood**

[Mica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mica#Properties_and_uses)

> These sheets are chemically inert, dielectric, elastic, flexible, hydrophilic, insulating, lightweight, platy, reflective, refractive, resilient, and range in opacity from transparent to opaque. Mica is stable when exposed to electricity, light, moisture, and extreme temperatures. It has superior electrical properties as an insulator and as a dielectric, and can support an electrostatic field while dissipating minimal energy in the form of heat;

But it won't be appropriate for lining a wooden cupboard containing a dangerous main breaker box. Adding [bodges](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bodge) over other bodges never turns a bodge into anything sane. The right solution for that is to tear everything out and rebuild that part of the installation to code.

Answer (score 3):

Been thinking about this one. This is an XY problem.  The "X" is that OP needs to add additional conduit entrances into a main panel that is *entirely inset into concrete*.  Only the lid is accessible.  Busting out concrete isn't really an option because some of the cables are large and need a wide sweep.  OP's only answer is to leave the deadfront completely off the panel, and feed the cables in the front, obscuring the breakers themselves with spaghetti cable.

---

So here is what I would do, legal though it is not.  First, one piece of prep work: the circuits exiting the top right of the main panel, feed them all out of the subpanel, so they avoid the main panel entirely.   If you need to splice them, fit a junction box above the main panel and splice them there.  Now they are out of the way and the only interconnects needed are to the subpanel to the left.

I would mount a gutter (large junction box) so it overlaps the entire bottom edge of the panel by about 3 inches (75mm). The overlap allows creation of a wide hole in the back of the gutter that leads into the panel space.

Then, I enter my surface conduits plural, into the sides of the gutter. Wires continue through the back hole, into the panel.  Nothing (but the gutter) blocks the panel cover. No cables or conduits cross the front of the panel in any way.

Because the cover is going back on the panel.

Now the only thing that interferes with putting the panel cover back on is the gutter.  So (after test fitting gutter but before drilling any screws to mount it or running wires) fully reinstall the panel cover and mark the edge where it interferes with the gutter.  That becomes a fold line.  Cut an inch beyond the line, then take the panel cover to a metal brake and have it folded on that line.  That fold will become a flange that will contact the gutter for a good seal. Itvwill also stiffen it somewhat.

Go back and reinstall the panel cover properly.

Now, install the gutter physically so it is flush up against this flange.

Now the panel cover is on, the wide hole in the back of the gutter allows you to bring conduit into the ends or bottom of the gutter (without crossing the panel cover, mind you) and route those cables into the panel.

The result is a *[neat and workmanlike](https://www.electrical-contractor.net/forums/ubbthreads.php/topics/81263/What_is_neat_and_workmanlike.html) (NEC 110.12)* installation that is reasonably safe and serviceable.

The last detail that needs to be attended is removal of the cabinets, as their presence violates the [working space around panels](https://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/working-space) rule.

Comment: Please see completely edit pictures where I showed how I joined 3 circuits/breakers into 1 breaker in subpanel. If I'd put them in the gutter box. Should I continue to use wire nut to join 3 wires together?

Comment: "entirely inset into concrete." is that wtf is going on here, +1. Still, I'm going to have to call BS on this whole thing. It should've been a sub-panel after busting out some concrete to get to a knock out.

Comment: @Harper. Please see edited post for the picture of the cover. And also consider my main panel without EGC argument. Do you think it's sound, that without EGC, the panel cover can just increase the risk.. so would just treat the whole panel as live all the time and needing to first shut down the main breaker in the street or the 2nd disconnect before touching the panel. What do you think?